# using callback functions in dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I am  using the jQuery dialog.  I want to be able to use the script for a single the dialog for more than one use.  To do so, I am thinking of assigning some callback function which can be called in the dialog.  Is this an appropriate way to do so?  What do I need to do to make the below code alert "hi" when the dialog button is clicked?  Thank you

```
function somefunction() {alert('hi');}

$("#clickme").click(function(){$("#dialog").data('callback',somefunction).dialog("open");});

$("#dialog").dialog({
    buttons: [
    {
        text    : 'Click',
        click   : function() {
            //If $(this).data('callback') is defined, then execute the function 
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways to do it (all shown in the documenation).

Here's one way (the simplest in my opinion):

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
       "Click": function() {
            alert("Hi");
            // execute callback if it is defined
            if (callback) callback();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using this same dialog on multiple pages.  I want consistent look (resizable : false,height : 300,width : 440,modal : true,dialogClass : 'hide-title-bar',etc) and want the same open function().  I don’t want to duplicate this over each page, and want to use the same dialog, but apply it differently.  Sometimes button() might alert(‘hi’), other times it might modify some DOM.  Thus I want it to execute the callback() function in which I will include whatever script necessary.

Comment: so.... include the callback function instead of the anonymous function? I dont understand.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I have some other code in my anonymous function which is common to all pages.  I want to execute that code and then if the call back function is defined, execute its code.

Comment: Where would the callback be defined? could you just use `if (callback) callback()`?

Comment: Looks like this is all I needed to do.  See http://jsfiddle.net/yxYvk/.  Update your answer, and I will select it as the best answer.  Thanks!